# New Object Instances are not running the Customized Initializer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, oop

I am working on a project that contains a Singleton instance of a class called Survey. Within that singleton instance is a property called "itemArray," which is an NSMutableArray that contains any number of instances of an Item class.

My Items class contains several NSInteger properties, but for the purposes of the application, I need to initialize all NSIntegers with a value of -1 instead of the default 0.

Now, for my Survey class (the one with the Singleton instance), I use the following method in the implementation to change the default value of a property:

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _thingy = -1;
        }
    return self;
}
```

This works, but for some reason, the same exact syntax (with different properties) doesn't work for instances of my Item instances. For what it's worth, the following codeblock is the creation of 2 instances of Item, and their insertion into itemArray. I also tried the Item *item1 = [[Item alloc]init; method to no avail.

```
Item *item1;
[[[Survey sharedInstance]itemArray]insertObject:item1 atIndex:0];
Item *item2;
[[[Survey sharedInstance]itemArray]insertObject:item2 atIndex:1];
}
```

I would appreciate any assistance.

!!!!!UPDATE!!!!! 
I entered the following conditional:

```
if (![[Survey sharedInstance]itemArray]){
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

And the "test" logged onto the console, so it looks like the itemArray isn't being initialized. I'm not sure how to actually initialize it, though. When I try the following:

```
  [[Survey sharedInstance]addressArray] = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

I'm getting an error saying "Expression is not assignable."

Survey.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Survey : NSObject

+(instancetype)sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *emailAddress;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger trigger1;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger trigger2;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger trigger3;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger activeItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *itemArray;

@end
```

Survey.m

```
#import "Survey.h"

@implementation Survey


+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static Survey *_instance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _instance = [[Survey alloc] init];
    });
    return _instance;
}

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _storage = -1;
        }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Is the custom `-init` method in your `Item` class or your `Survey` class?

Comment: There is one for each. I have to set default values of NSInteger properties to -1 for both of those classes. The -init property above is the one in the Survey class, though the one in the Item class is identical, just with different properties.

Comment: The way you are creating the `Item`s is incorrect.  You aren't using `alloc`/`init`.  This is undefined behavior (since `item1` and `item2` point to random memory) and will likely crash.  Use `alloc`/`init`.  I know you said it didn't work.  Try it, and add an `NSLog` to `-[Item init]`.  Then let us know if anything is logged.

Comment: I entered an NSLog to print "test" whenever the custom init is run, and even though it does, it's still not giving me a good result. I also entered NSLogs to print out the length of the array after adding item1 and item2, but it's returning a result of 0. Also, when I try to print out the value of one of the properties that should have been changed to -1, it still returns a 0.

Comment: Could you post a sample project? There is something else going on that we can't tell from your post.

Comment: What's the superclass of `Item`?

Comment: Actually, I may have found the root of the problem. Updated posted in main section of the post.

Comment: Superclass of Item is NSObject.

Comment: Can we see your whole `Survey` class?  With your update, I think I know how to fix it, but I need a bit more info.

Comment: You never create you Item objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 [[Survey sharedInstance]addressArray] = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

you need to use

```
 [Survey sharedInstance].addressArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

or

```
[[Survey sharedInstance] setAddressArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]];
```

You were trying to assign a value to the return value of a getter method, which is not possible, so the compiler was saying "Expression not assignable."  You need to use the setter method or dot notation instead.

Comment: Everything works now. That did it. I cannot thank you enough. Absolute lifesaver.

Comment: This is definitely a bug, but I fail to see how it gets his Items created.

Comment: @HotLicks The problem was that he wasn't initializing the array.  Jesse's change was required, he just said he had tried it and it didn't work.  The reason this wasn't working appears to be because he was trying to access a `nil` array.  Calling a method on a `nil` object returns `nil`, 0, `NO`, etc.  He accessed the array and it returned nil.  Then he tried to access one of the properties on the object and it was 0, so he assumed that his initializer hadn't ran.  When he added an `NSLog` to his initializer, it logged (after applying Jesse's solution).

Comment: @NobodyNada - Then why was Jesse's answer downvoted?

Comment: @HotLicks , the question was answered by NobodyNada. There is no need to continue this.

Comment: @JayB127 - The question was "why doesn't this work".  The above answer is only part of the total answer.

Comment: @HotLicks You are correct, and I would un-downvote if my vote was't locked in.  I downvoted because the question said that using `alloc`/`init` didn't fix it.  At the point Jesse's answer was posted, we didn't have _nearly_ enough information to know what the real problem was.  I can edit that info into my answer if you want, but I can't retract the down vote unless Jesse's post is edited.